# Looking for recommendations on modeling a problem

Tags: metric-spaces, mathematical-modeling, modal-logic

I didn't know what tags I should use for sure; so apologies if not appropriate or enough ones.

Suppose we have 5 people answering 20 yes/no questions. One of them, call her *a*, is fixed as the one whose answers are assumed to be the correct ones, the answers of the other 4 being evaluated in comparison to *a*'s: if their answer to a certain question corresponds to *a*'s answer, they will get a pass for that question, otherwise fail. Now, repeat the whole scenario for each and every one of the other members of the group: each time, fix someone (among the 5) as a reference, and evaluate others' responses compared to her's. Finally, suppose we repeat the entire scenario so far for 4 other groups of 5 people.

I'm interested to know what kind of mathematical modeling method you'd recommend to express this scenario. I have been thinking of modeling this in terms of possible worlds semantics and also metric spaces, but haven't proceeded much so far.

Any approach is welcome. Please let me know if clarifications are needed.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you modeling?  If we are given the $5\times 20=100$ responses then we can simply compute the scores according to the rules you gave, nothing to model. Did you mean to say that the responses are drawn from some sort of distribution?  If so, we need information regarding that process.

Comment: @lulu I'm interested to know how to reconstruct/express/capture the *relativity* of the true answers in the scenario in a mathematical way: there's not going to be *absolute* truths; just that by each time assuming someone's answer's as true, we're scoring other's responses. Does this help?

Comment: Not really.  Like I say, if I have the responses I can just score everybody according to the rules you gave.  There's simply nothing to model.   Again, if you had a distribution...something like "everybody has a high probability of getting each question absolutely right but there are (possibly correlated) sources of noise around each question that can cause errors"  then you can model the effect of those noise sources on your relative scores.  But, really, I don't understand what you are asking.  Say you had $2$ people and $2$ questions.  What are you asking about that?

Comment: We have 2 people a and b and 2 questions. I want to know how I can express the idea that the truth of b's answer depends on a's, disregarding of what their answers are. **Suppose we're not aware of the answers of a and b**; I just know the rule that once b is evaluated in terms of a, and once the other way around. Now I can't use the responses sheet (because I'm not aware of them), but still want to express the way the evaluation is done, in a mathematical way, to aliens who don't understand English, but do understand mathematics.

Comment: Put differently, I want to express the very rules of the scenario, somehow mathematically.

Comment: Ok...so for two subjects $i,j$ and question $n$ we define $F_{i,j}(n)=1$ if they answer the same way on question $n$ and $0$ if they don't.  We remark that $F_{i,j}(n)=F_{j,i}(n)$ for all $n$.  Perhaps you only care about the sum  $G(i,j)=\sum_n F_{i,j}(n)$.